# How to configure Heimdal Kerberos to use OpenLDAP?

Tags: kerberos, openbsd, make, heimdal

From http://www.h5l.org/manual/HEAD/info/heimdal/Using-LDAP-to-store-the-database.html#Using-LDAP-to-store-the-database

> A current release of Heimdal, configured with --with-openldap=/usr/local

The OpenBSD package of Heimdal is not configured with OpenLDAP support. I would like compile it with OpenLDAP support.

I downloaded the OpenBSD ports tree and installed it. I can `make` the heimdal port, but I'm not sure exactly how to configure it to use OpenLDAP

I tried adding `--with-openldap=/usr/local/bin` to `CONFIGURE_ARGS` in `Makefile`, and make ran, but OpenLDAP wasn't included

> It's also possible to configure the ldap backend as a shared module, see option –hdb-openldap-module to configure

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried again with a fresh install of OpenBSD. Works now

I installed the openldap-client first using `pkg_add`

in `/usr/ports/security/heimdal/Makefile`, I changed:

```
CONFIGURE_ARGS +=   --bindir=${PREFIX}/heimdal/bin \
                    --sbindir=${PREFIX}/heimdal/sbin \
                    --libexecdir=${PREFIX}/heimdal/libexec \
                    --libdir=${PREFIX}/heimdal/lib \
                    --includedir=${PREFIX}/heimdal/include
```

to

```
CONFIGURE_ARGS +=   --bindir=${PREFIX}/heimdal/bin \
                    --sbindir=${PREFIX}/heimdal/sbin \
                    --libexecdir=${PREFIX}/heimdal/libexec \
                    --libdir=${PREFIX}/heimdal/lib \
                    --includedir=${PREFIX}/heimdal/include \
                    --with-openldap=${LOCALBASE}
```

Then I ran `make install` and tested that it works using `kdc --builtin-hdb`